# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Angular 4 + C# rest

Tags: c#, angular, rest

I'm using angular 4 as front end , and C# as back end for building a rest api .

I'm trying to send a PhotoString as parameter from angular to Rest api .
The photo String is too large (binary) :

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAI......
```

I'm receiving No access Control Allow Origin as error response .

The code below of calling the rest api :

```
this.headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });



SaveFoto(user: User) {
     return this.http.put(this.URL+ user.id + '&photoString=' + 
     user.photo, JSON.stringify(user), this.options)
       .map((res: Response) => {
        console.log(res);
        res.json();
       });
 }
```

My Rest API tested and works fine :

```
    [Route("api/ce/updateFoto")]
    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("updateFoto")]
    public string updateFoto(int id, string photoString)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        try
        {

            cnn.myConnection.Open();
            cmd.Connection = cnn.myConnection;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "update user set photo= convert(VARBINARY(max), '"+ photoString +"') where id=" + id;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            cnn.myConnection.Close();
        }
        return "ok";
    }
```

**What i tried :**
 - inserting manually in sql server the query, its works fine .
 - inserting a small photoString works fine.
 - Enabling cors on chrome
 - Enabling cors in webApiConfig.cs by installing cors as reference and with this code :

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

The problem persists. It is because the string is too large, so the error appears.

Any help ??

**Edit :**

**The full request link :**

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://SERVERADRESS/project/api/ce/updateFoto?id=8&photo=data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAgAElEQVR4AezBB3yeZ2Hv7+/9PO/S3rItD8......

The string is too large i cant put it all.

**The response :**

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 414.

Comment: can you post the request and response?

Comment: Edited it already

Comment: 1 - why do you pass photo as string in url?
2 - why do you pass user in body but in backend you you don't accept data from request body?

Comment: 1- pass photo as string or course ! how can i pass it in another way ? its the only way to get it and store in the sql server 
2- because i tried to pass the foto in the body before

Comment: @belhadjhaythem the photo for the data should be passed in the _body_.  Passing as part of the URL is the most ridiculous thing I have ever seen.

Comment: Also, you have a _huge_ SQL injection vulnerability in your code.  **Always use parameters**

Comment: @maccettura how should i pass it ! how can it be in the webservice ?

Comment: @belhadjhaythem I would **strongly** suggest taking some basic tutorials on Javascript/AJAX, REST and how to avoid SQL injection attacks in your C# code.

Comment: In Angular you pass the json body as the [second parameter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put) of `put()`. Make your WebApi accept an object that contains all the data you need, then mimic that on your front end code.

Comment: I tried it, passing only the id in parameters and the all the user in the body but it still the same error

Comment: Regardless of any other problems you’re having, you need to remove `this.headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' })` from your request code. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a *response* header that servers return in response to requests. The only effect that adding it to a request is ever going to have is to break things.